# How to add object into an array which is a value of a key within an object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user model like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    courses: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})
```

And a course model like this:

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    course_code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    course_title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

app.js file is here:

```
app.post('/enroll/:id', async function (req, res) {
    const courseWithID = await Course.findById(req.params.id)
    const course = {"course_code": courseWithID.course_code, "course_title": courseWithID.course_title}
    const userID = req.user.id
    
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userID, {"courses": course}, {new: true, runValidators: true, useFindAndModify: false})
    res.redirect('/dashboard')
})
```

After first execution of app.js, I get this result:

```
    {
        "name": "Person",
        "courses": {
            "course_code": "123",
            "course_title": "ABC"
        }
    }
```

After second execution of app.js, I get this result:

```
    {
        "name": "Person",
        "courses": {
            "course_code": "456",
            "course_title": "DEF"
        }
    }
```

But after second execution of app.js, I want this result:

```
{
    "name": "Person",
    "courses": [
        {
            "course_code": "123",
            "course_title": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "course_code": "456",
            "course_title": "DEF"
        }
    ]
}
```

How Can I do that?

Comment: I have used:
`User.findByIdAndUpdate(userID, {$push: {"courses": {"course_code": "123", "course_title": "ABC"}}}`
and
`courses: [{
        course_code: {type: String, required: true},
        course_title: {type: String, required: true}
    }]`

But it says The field 'courses' must be an array but is of type object.
@turivishal

Comment: @TahsinAlMahi you have to update the ```userSchema``` and change ```courses``` type to ```Array``` instead of ```Object``` to push the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fixes,

- change `courses` type `Object` to an `Array`

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    courses: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
})
```

- add [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) before `courses` because we need to push object in array

```
const courseWithID = await Course.findById(req.params.id);
const course = {
  "course_code": courseWithID.course_code, 
  "course_title": courseWithID.course_title
};
const userID = req.user.id;

await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userID, 
  {
    "$push": { "courses": course }
  }, 
  {new: true, runValidators: true, useFindAndModify: false}
)
```